# How to implement automorphisms technique in SEAL?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

In the [SEAL homomorphic encryption library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/simple-encrypted-arithmetic-library-seal-v2-1/), no automorphisms technique to move values between the different slots in a given plaintext vector is provided. How could this technique be implemented in SEAL?

Comment: could you link the SEAL's version you are referring to?

Comment: https://sealcrypto.codeplex.com/. SEAL V2.1

Comment: do you understand the theory (algebra) behind those packing techniques?

Comment: I understand the theory CRT behind those packing technique